# C++ class template with non-type parameter depending on type parameter problem using C++11

Tags: c++, specialization

I understand that the normal means in C++ of controlling at compile time which class template member functions are included/excluded is through partial specialization. I have a class template which has a type parameter and a non-type parameter depending on the type parameter. When the non-type parameter is a certain value I want certain member functions of a class template to be part of the instantiation of the class template but not others. The normal way of doing this is to code the primary template to include certain member functions and then to code a partial specialization of the primary template with a different set of member functions. But because of the rule which says:

"Non-type template argument cannot specialize a template parameter whose type depends on a parameter of the specialization" I can not do this. Is there a way around this ? Simple example code would look like:

```
  template 
    <
    class T, 
    T * v
    >
  struct  AClassTemple
    {
    void SomeMemberFunction() { code etc. }
    void AnotherMemberFunction() { code etc. }
    };
```

When 'v' is a nullptr I want my class template to not include AnotherMemberFunction and its code, which assumes a value for 'v' which is not a nullptr. I can not partially specialize the class template by specifying:

```
  template 
    <
    class T 
    >
  struct  AClassTemple<T,nullptr>
     {
     };
```

etc. else I get a compiler error reflecting the rule above.

Comment: Mmm. Whether `v` is `nullptr` or not could be not known at compile time...

Comment: Whether v is nullptr ot not is always known at compile time. When the end-user instantiates the class template he is either passing a nullptr as the argument to the second template parameter or not. A non-type template parameter is always a compile time value.

Comment: That's what I'm implying. What I mean is: if the end user has to manually write `AClassTemplate<sometype,nullptr>` or `AClassTemplate<sometype,non_null_ptr>` to select the two cases, why don't you make him just write `ClassTemplateA<sometype>` and `ClassTemplateB<sometype>`? What's the advantage of using a non-type template parameter to distinguish two cases, if that parameter is not deducible? However, if you know that parameter is known at compile time, then the answer you've received does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The following should do what you want:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, T *v>
struct AClassTemple {
    template<T *w = v, class = std::enable_if_t<w != nullptr>>
    void SomeMemberFunction() {}

    template<T *w = v, class = std::enable_if_t<w != nullptr>>
    void AnotherMemberFunction() {}
};

int main() {
    constexpr static char c = '0';
    AClassTemple<int, nullptr> a{};
    AClassTemple<const char, &c> b{};

    // a.SomeMemberFunction(); // will not compile
    b.SomeMemberFunction();
}
```

Comment: Based on how the question is posed, I would stress the following, even if it's obvious: this solution (and any solution to, actually) works only if you pass a constant expression (such as the `nullptr` literal or a `constexpr` variable) as non-type argument. Doing `int * x = nullptr; AClassTemple<int, x> a{};` wouldn't work, for instance.